# How do get into the BIOS (InsydeH2O rev 5.0) of my HP laptop to make it ACPI compliant?

Tags: laptop, bios, acpi

My laptop (HP Laptop 15-bw0xx) setup utility (BIOS) is InsydeH2O rev 5.0 for an HP laptop.

I am trying to get the BIOS to be fully ACPI compliant as I only get a blue screen I got during setup:

```
 *** STOP: 0x000000A5 (0x00000003, 0x8A4C1E80, 0xC0140001, 0x494E495F)
```

I need a way to get into the advanced tab in my BIOS. Plus the laptop has no OS installed which is why I am trying to download Windows XP onto it. No other OS booted into setup which is why I wanna do Windows XP because it did boot into setup.

How do I make my device ACPI compliant?

Comment: Please don't rant. Instead, provide details about he BSOD. All the prose is irrelevant, only the numbers (and sometimes filenames) contain relevant information.

Comment: What is the model of your laptop? Please [edit] your question.

Comment: @DavidPostill i dont know the model but the product name is HP laptop 15-bw0xx and the "system family" is HP notebook

Comment: @DanielB the numbers on the BSOD are:     *** STOP: 0x000000A5 (0x00000003, 0x8A4C1E80, 0xC0140001, 0x494E495F)

Comment: https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Hardware-and-Upgrade-Questions/Device-ACPI-SMB0001-3-amp-2411E6FE-amp-0-requires-further/td-p/7977378

Answer (score 3):

Your laptop is too new and no longer compatible with Windows XP. You cannot run Windows XP on it directly, but depending on your exact use case, virtual machine software could be used to run Windows XP inside a more modern host OS.

Windows XP is crashing because an ACPI method is failing. You (mostly) cannot change what these methods do using configuration, they are part of fixed BIOS/UEFI firmware programming. The only way to change them is by upgrading the firmware. However, even an upgraded version will not be compatible with Windows XP.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I understand but i do not know how to access ADVANCED as it is not there. i have tried things that people said like: fn+tab 3x                 /      f10+a       and nothing worked

Comment: @Humancoder1123 Odd. My suggestion is the answers posted here are solid. If they don’t work for you, just wait and see if someone else comes along and can add their advice to the mix. Not much else can be said or done past that.

Answer (score 3):

An answer from the post
[THERE IS NO ADVANCED TAB IN BIOS SETTINGS INSYDEH20](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Software-and-How-To-Questions/THERE-IS-NO-ADVANCED-TAB-IN-BIOS-SETTINGS-INSYDEH20/td-p/7917970)
says that :

> Sorry, but apart from business notebooks and some high-end gaming PCs,
> accessing Advanced BIOS option on HP PCs is not possible.
>
> Some OEMs lock out the advanced BIOS options to prevent customers from
> making changes to options that can destabilize or otherwise damage the
> PC -- and then send it back for repair under warranty claiming they
> did nothing to it.
>
> I know only SOME of the advanced options are risky, but it's simpler
> to disable access to ALL advanced options than to allow/disallow on an
> individual option basis.
>
> That's the course of action that HP has chosen.

For HP computers where unlocking the Advanced tab is possible, the
[first method](https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/unlock-insydeh20-advanced-settings.3396290/)
listed is <kbd>F10</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> during boot.

The
[second method](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Operating-System-and-Recovery/Unlock-Advanced-BIOS-Settings/td-p/8369277)
that is counseled in more than one post is:

> To Access Advanced BIOS Settings in HP
>
> 1. Restart your Computer. Stop whatever you are doing.
> 2. Enter BIOS Settings. Press the Esc key repeatedly until the Startup menu opens.
> 3. Power Off/ Restart your Computer. Power off or restart your computer again, and this time press F9.
> 4. Press F10 and Get the Advanced Tab.

If none of these methods works for your model, then
there is no "advanced settings" for it.
The implementation by a vendor can vary, and there apparently was
at one point one or more versions of InsydeH20 that had an "advanced"
feature, but it's not commonplace.